# Can I define group-specific environmental variables?

Tags: bash

I want to setup some environmental variables for all the users of a specific group. I can modify the .bash_profile of all the users in the group, but this does not work for future new users, hence I want to insert an if statement in /etc/profile of this kind:

```
if [`id -G` -eq GROUP_ID]; then
  export PATH=$PATH:...
fi
```

But, I have problems because the users belong to more than one group.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
if groups | grep -w -q <GROUP_NAME>; then
  export PATH=$PATH:...
fi
```

Comment: if you were going to do any sort of security based on that, I would be more particular about the check because `echo "group1 group2 wikiroot" | grep root` would match

Comment: @TomH: You are perfectly right, I'm editing my answer. Adding -w to grep should solve that problem.